# How to check if Uri has sftp scheme, using standard methods in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, uri, sftp

I have address - sftp://someserver:1234/files/file.txt

For example to check if Uri has Ftp scheme:

```
var uri = new Uri(address);
if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
{
    //...
}
```

But there is no default scheme for sftp. 
How can I check it without string parsing? 
Only using standard methods.

Answer (score 0):

`Uri.Scheme` will return the `string` scheme part, so you can check it as like doing with `UriSchemeFtp` (this is a `string` field, not an `enum`):

```
if (string.Equals(uri.Scheme, "sftp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you totally, but I thought that exists some const system value for Sftp.